# How to access application scoped cdi bean packed as jboss shared library

Tags: java, maven, jboss, cdi

I have to use an application scoped cdi bean present in jboss shared libraries in my ear application.

Example:

```
jboss\modules\com\test\test.jar
```

In test.jar I have one application scoped bean

```
@ApplicationScoped

public class Test {

    @Inject
    SomeClass someClass;

    @PostConstructor
    public void init() {
        someClass.doSomething();
    }

    public void testMethod() {
    }
}
```

myapp.ear → ejb.jar

In ejb.jar I have one class which initializes Test application scoped bean.

```
public class Another {

    @Inject
    Test test;

    public void myMethod() {
        test.testMethod();
    }
}
```

When I test this example, I'll get null pointer exception as I'm trying to inject application scoped bean which is out side an ear application.

Note: I cannot have test.jar in my ear lib directory, as per my requirement it will be delivered as jboss shared library.

Any ideas how to access application scoped bean?

Comment: What version of jboss are you using? Is your test.jar a well structured jboss module (module.xml)? Did you reference that module either via you ear manifest (Dependencies) or jboss-deployment-structure.xml? Does your module include a beans.xml?

Comment: i'm using jboss 6 eap, yes test.jar is a well structured jboss module with module.xml. I tried adding jboss-deployment-structure with export="true" and meta-inf="export". and my ejb module contains beans.xml in META-INF directory.

Comment: Test class application scoped bean, is actually packed in another ear application, there it is working fine, as I need to reuse the same code/logic, I made it as a jboss shared library and using it in my application. Also able to instantiate all other non CDI classes but not able to get that application scoped bean.

Is there any way to get that application bean from jboss shared library?

Answer (score 1):

Add beans.xml to META-INF directory of your test.jar. In this case container will scan test.jar file for CDI beans.
This is also strange that you get NPE. You would get "unsatisfied dependencies" if injected bean was not found. Probably you instantiate Test bean incorrectly. For example, via the New operator.

Comment: This answer was just what I needed to enable a CDI enabled library to a service. Thank you so much! :-)